# MongoDB index for nested document is not being used

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In my collection, I've say the following structure

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("ssxxdfasfsadf"),
  a: {
    b: "somevalue"
  }
}
```

I've created an index for `a.b`, which works fine if I use find query as `db.collection.find({"a.b": "someothervalue"})`.

If I change my query to `db.collection.find({a: {b: "somevalue"}})`, it's doing a complete collection scan. (Source - `find().explain()`)

Sure, I can modify my application to do the query as `"a.b"`, but I want to avoid that, as I've few other fields in `a`, on which in future I may need to query.

Is there anyway `{a: {b: "somevalue"}}` could work with tweaking the index?

Also, is there any advantage/disadvantage of using one or the other?

Comment: You can create a index on embedded document as a whole if you are planning to match document as a whole. Index on embedded fields are different from indexes on embedded document. More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/#create-an-index-on-embedded-document. Based on your use case you can always create index/compound index on your embedded document fields.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the first approach. A quick read through MongoDB's documentation, states the following:

> MongoDB uses the dot notation to access the elements of an array and to access the fields of an embedded document.

See [MongoDB Dot Notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) and [Query on Embedded/Nested Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-fields-of-an-embedded-document).

---

About tweaking the index, you could [index the embedded document as a whole](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/#create-an-index-on-embedded-document):

```
db.myColl.createIndex({ "a": 1 });
```

But I don't see the reason of doing this if you only need specific properties indexed. I would be sensitive on the [Index Size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/), especially if the property will be holding a lot of data.

Comment: adding index on embedded document as a whole worked for me. thanks